# nodejs: Later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit

Tags: node.js

- **Version**:  8.0.0 / 7.6.0 / 7.7.1
- **Platform**: win 10 x64

i have installed 8.0.0 nightly before ( for use async )

when 7.6.0 out, i try install 7.6.0

installer show msg " Later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit "

i unzip Binary (.zip) for force install 7.6.0

but now

i wanna install 7.7.1

this msg show up again

i tryed search all node.js or 8.0.0 at Registry

and replace it to 7.6.0

the installer still not allow install

where can let me install new version without upzip for replace every time?

i can't use uninstaller

cos i don't sure what will be remove by uninstaller

my nodejs installed at msys2 folder

any way let me can do update new version by Windows Installer (.msi) ?

---

i just need update old nodejs version to Latest Current Version

by normal way at now and future

---

i didn't try uninstall,

cos my node install folder is "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin",

my node_modules at "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\node_modules",

im "not sure" uninstaller will "only" remove node js and npm only without delete other file at "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin"

Comment: So you need to run two version of Node on Windows side by side?

Comment: nope, i just need one version

Comment: What's the problem with uninstalling? What's the error?

Comment: are you trying to switch between different versions of node?

Comment: you may wish to consult/install `nvm-windows` (unfortunately, `n` and `nvm` are linux/mac)
[https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows]

Comment: i didn't try uninstall, cos my node install folder is "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin", my node_modules at "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\node_modules", im "not sure" uninstaller will "only" remove node js and npm only without delete other file at "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin"

Answer (score 7):

Execute the previous installed version of .msi (node-v8.9.0-x64.msi) file it will get in to the setup wizard and you can see the option for repair, remove, etc.. you can select remove, this will uninstall completely the previous version. now you can install your desired version.

Answer (score 5):

go to `Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Programs and Features`
remove Node JS.

Reinstall your preferred version from the Node JS website and good luck!
worked for me

Answer (score 3):

search file at

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js

Uninstall Node.js.lnk
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /x **{65370F5F-81AF-453E-BD85-A05B561DB989}**

search `65370F5F-81AF-453E-BD85-A05B561DB989` at Registry
(i use RegistryWorkshop

one of will like this
**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products** {xxx}
*ProductIcon*

edit DWORD **Version** 0x8000000 mean 8.0.0

edit it low or equal than version u wanna edit

like 0x7000000

than now can keep use installer like old day

Answer (score 0):

Change Your NPM Version to LTE
Check please `https://github.com/deepbag/nvs` it's the best solution for this problem.
Node Version Switcher - A cross-platform tool for switching between versions and forks of Node.js

Install NVS ---- Command Line Run Administration Mode
Windows:

```
choco install nvs
```

Mac|Linux :

```
export NVS_HOME="$HOME/.nvs"git clone https://github.com/jasongin/nvs "$NVS_HOME". "$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install
```

Add LTS Version NVS ---- Command Line Run Administration Mode

```
$ nvs add lts

$ nvs use lts (Output : PATH += ~/.nvs/node/6.9.1/x64)

$ nvs link lts

$ npm install -g npm
```

Successful Your NPM Version Changed and Updated

Answer (score 0):

For me I went to the below mentioned path and uninstalled the node.js this fixed the issue. Also removed the old environment variable which was setup

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js`